# How to create an expression from MemberInfo[]?

Tags: c#, expression

I need to create an `Expression<Func<T, object>>`from a `MemberInfo[]`.

Actually I want the Expression to be similar to that block of code:

```
x => new { x.A, x.B, x.C }
```

Comment: Using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), you can assign to a variable of type `Expression<Func<>>` your lambda, and then `Dump()` the variable to see how the `Expression` is constructed.

Comment: Note however: Unless you already have an anonymous type matching your `MemberInfo[]`, you can't easily or usefully create one at runtime - anonymous types are statically created by the compiler at compile time. It also wouldn't be very easy to find the one you want, and if you did create one at runtime, their is very little you can do with it that doesn't involve lots of reflection. Better off using a `Dictionary<string,object>` or `ExpandoObject` or a custom class based off `DynamicObject`.

Comment: Oh, I understood. Thank you.